# Extract Substring from jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, performance

I know this is a popular topic and I've read some other articles on substring selection in jQuery, but can't figure out how to get my specific example working more efficiency and any advice would be appreciated.

I have the following code:

```
$('#plan-gallery').click(function(){
    $('#gallery').addClass('active-slide') 
    $('#gallery').fadeIn() 
});

$('#plan-ensuite').click(function(){
    $('#ensuite').addClass('active-slide') 
    $('#ensuite').fadeIn() 
});

$('#plan-bedroom').click(function(){
    $('#bedroom').addClass('active-slide') /* This code line is redundant */
    $('#bedroom').fadeIn() /* This code line is also redundant */
});
```

This kind of code is repeated many times throughout my script.js and I'd like to get rid of it's redundancy.

Can any jQuery wizards help make my code better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: provided an example w/ markup in my post below...

Comment: @pixelhobby, thats nice for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the id of the slide starts after the first `-` in the slide button id:

```
$('#plan-gallery,#plan-ensuite,#plan-bedroom').click(function(){
   $('#' + this.id.substring(this.id.indexOf('-') + 1)).addClass('active-slide').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really want to write the code like that you can split the `id` attribute on the `-` and use the second part to form a new selector. Also you can chain your jQuery calls onto each other.

```
$("#plan-gallery, #plan-ensuite, #plan-bedroom").live("click", function(){
    $("#" + $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]).addClass('active-slide').fadeIn() 
});
```

However I wouldn't mix the target I want to do something on into the `id` of what I'm clicking since the end up being tightly coupled. Consider something like this instead, which would let you specify what it is you want to target, and you wouldn't have to update the jQuery selector each time you have a new thing:

```
<a href="#" id="plan-gallery" class="plan" data-target="#gallery">Gallery</a>
<a href="#" class="plan" data-target=".images">All images</a>

$(".plan").live("click", function(){
    $($(this).data("target")).addClass('active-slide').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your HTML. Assuming #plan-gallery is `<a>`:

```
<a href="#" class="opener" rel="gallery">Gallery</a>
<a href="#" class="opener" rel="ensuite">Ensuite</a>
<a href="#" class="opener" rel="bedroom">Bedroom</a>

<div id="gallery">...</div>
<div id="ensuite">...</div>
<div id="bedroom">...</div>
```

Then you could do it like this:

```
$('a.opener').click(function(){
    $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active-slide').fadeIn();
```

});

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
//for example
$('#plan-gallery').click(function(){
    addandfade(this);
});

$('#plan-ensuite').click(function(){
    addandfade(this);
});

$('#plan-bedroom').click(function(){
    addandfade(this);
});

function addandfade(obj){
   var open_id = obj.id.substring(obj.id.indexOf('-') + 1); //thanks @Dan
   $("#"+open_id).addClass('active-slide').fadeIn();
}
```

And you can use that same function over and over

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/teCFV/

Comment: That still requires you to repeat the first three lines for each bit.

Comment: @pixelhobby... thats for that click, each click is a diff id

Comment: This is the closest solution and is fine, but is there any way I could get rid of hard coding the #gallery bit, with regex or something (anal I know)? btw, I know what regex is but I've never used it before(!) so I wouldn't know how to write it

Comment: one sec. im going to try to make a combo solution of mine and @Dan's

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for your help Neal, StackOverFlow is truly the best resource a web designer could ever hope for in terms of coding.

Answer (score -2):

you could do something like this if you're able to change the mark-up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.nav div').click(function(){
        //hide all slides
        $('.sliders div').hide();

        //make active w/ id attr
        var tag = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.sliders').find(tag).show();
    });
</script>

<div class="nav">
    <div id="slide-1"><img src="..."/></div>
    <div id="slide-2"><img src="..."/></div>
    <div id="slide-3"><img src="..."/></div>
</div>

<div class="sliders">
    <div class="slide-1"></div>
    <div class="slide-2"></div>
    <div class="slide-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: every click does something different to a different id

Comment: @Neal first off, I don't think it's cool when you post an answer that's no better than the other ones here and downvote everyone else (even if you do have 7k rep).  Also, I mentioned adding if-logic to determine the element so it could be reusable code...

Comment: I'm the first one who recommended comma separated selectors :P

Comment: @pixelhobby, yes, but you removed it

Answer (score -2):

I think something like this would work:

```
$('#plan-gallery,#plan-bedroom,#plan-ensuite').click(function(){
    $(this).child().addClass('active-slide') 
    $(this).child().fadeIn() 
});
```

Comment: I was considering that the for example $gallery is a child of #plan-gallery